# UIBarButton on PickerView doesn't wok

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

What I want to do is to get an action evnet from the bar button. At the beginning, I put the bar button on the bar tool on on pickerview. The button display on the pickerview, but I couldn't push the button. The color of the button doesn't change at all. It means I cannot touch the button. The pickerview can be scrolled even on the button area. It seems like the button is under the pickerview. 
 Once I add the tool bar with slef.view.adSubView directly on the view, I could push the bar button and get the action. I want to get an action from the bar button on the picker view. I don't use these UIs on main story board for this time.

```
var pickerView1: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
var toolBar1 = UIToolbar()
var barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem()
let strData: [String] = ["abc","xyz"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // init bar button
    barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "PUSH", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("pushBarButton:"))
    barButton1.enabled = true
    // init tool bar
    toolBar1.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar1.translucent = true
    toolBar1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar1.sizeToFit()
    toolBar1.delegate = self
    // init picker
    pickerView1.delegate = self
    pickerView1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, (self.view.bounds.height/3)*2, self.view.bounds.width , self.view.bounds.height / 3.0 )

    // add button on tool bar
    toolBar1.setItems([barButton1], animated: true)
    // add tool bar on picker
    pickerView1.addSubview(toolBar1)
    // add picker on view
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView1)
}

func pushBarButton( sender: AnyObject){
    pickerView1.hidden = true
}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return strData.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return strData[row]
}
```

I use Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you was not able to push the button may be due to `UserInteractionEnabled` was not selected in xib.

Anyways, please try this to add programmatically:

`barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title:"PUSH",style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,target:self,action: Selector("pushBarButton"))`

`func pushBarButton(){
    pickerView1.hidden = true
}`

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Though I tried that, the result is the same. I also put {pickerView1.userInteractionEnbale = true}. It doesn't work.